# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_from_compatible_tensor_list'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I've been following this [Kaggle Notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/mrigendraagrawal/tpu-tutorial-vgg16-from-scratch) with my own dataset except that I directly input my gcs path wihout using the KaggleDataset() function that was used on that notebook.

Edit:
I'm running this code on Google Colab Notebook so I can't run the KaggleDataset() function

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import keras.layers as L

try:
    tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
    print("Device:", tpu.master())
    tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
    tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
    strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(tpu)
except:
    strategy = tf.distribute.get_strategy()
print("Number of replicas:", strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)

AUTO = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

IMAGE_SIZE = [224,224]
GCS_PATH = 'gs://classifai_bucket/classifai'

training_file = tf.io.gfile.glob(GCS_PATH+'/FineTune_Train/*.tfrec')
test_file = tf.io.gfile.glob(GCS_PATH+'/FineTune_Test/*.tfrec')

BATCH_SIZE = 16 * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync

ds_train = get_training_dataset()
ds_test = get_test_dataset()

ds_iter = iter(ds_train.unbatch().batch(20))
one_batch = next(ds_iter)
```

On that last line of code, I got this error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py in _next_internal(self)
    786         # Fast path for the case `self._structure` is not a nested structure.
--> 787         return self._element_spec._from_compatible_tensor_list(ret)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    788       except AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_from_compatible_tensor_list'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OutOfRangeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
14 frames
OutOfRangeError: End of sequence

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OutOfRangeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
OutOfRangeError: End of sequence

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py in __next__(self)
    797       return self._next_internal()
    798     except errors.OutOfRangeError:
--> 799       raise StopIteration
    800 
    801   @property

StopIteration:
```

I tried searching for similar problems but I haven't seen one